# Nursing if pregnant again

Tags: cats, pregnancy

If a cat becomes pregnant again after giving birth, will it affect some of the cats, and if so, is there a way I can help?

To make a clear question out of it:

**What special needs do a cat have, which at the same time is nursing one litter and is pregnant with the next one?**

Comment: Welcome to Pets.SE! Can you please specify on what you need help with? Are you asking if a cat would need help before birth? After birth? During birth? If you could edit your question, we might be able to better understand and answer. Please visit https://pets.stackexchange.com/tour to view the tour and better learn how to ask a question.